# How can I suppress globbing in parameter expansion?

Tags: bash, glob, parameter-expansion

Is there a way to suppress globbing in parameter expansion? Consider the case of a file named literally `*.xml` in a directory among other xml files. Is there a way to do a parameter expansion `${param##*/}` affecting only the file `*.xml` and not all the xml files?

```
param=./*.xml
echo "$param" # Displays only ./*.xml
echo $param # Displays ./*.xml ./invoice.xml ./bla.xml ...
echo ${param##*/} # Displays *.xml invoice.xml bla.xml ...
# what I want:
echo ${param##*/} # Displays only *.xml
```

Comment: Quote everything. e.g. `echo "${param##*/}"`

Comment: @anubhava If you write this as an answer I will accept it

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies the quoting problems in the code, and what should be done about them.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds many other problems with shell code too.  It's a good idea to use it often to check your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

Problem is not quoting your BASH expressions that allows shell to expand globs or wildcards.

You should be using quotes in shell as:

```
param='./*.xml'
echo "$param"
echo "${param##*/}"
```

Comment: This is a problem if you want the parameter substitution to be null, `${param:-}` vs. `"${param:-}"`